# Nuances of Working with Tidy Trigger Pattern

Tags: apex, trigger, design-patterns

Am working on a project in an org where I have to work with [Dave Scott's Tidy, Streamlined, Bulkified Trigger Pattern](http://meltedwires.com/2013/06/05/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers-revisited/) also known as the [Trigger Factory](http://developer.force.com/cookbook/recipe/trigger-pattern-for-tidy-streamlined-bulkified-triggers) pattern which can be found in the Salesforce Cookbook. There are nuances to it that can make it difficult to work with for some use cases.

For example, one can't perform queries from within the Object Handler Class. That makes it difficult to use when one needs to query related records as they must be done in another helper class. Making those callouts appears to be something of a challenge as well. The "bulk before" and "bulk after" methods are iterators. As such, they're controlled by the for loop iterators in the Execute method of the Trigger Factory base class as per the code example below:

```
private static void execute(ITrigger handler)
{
    // Before Trigger
    if (Trigger.isBefore)
    {
        // Call the bulk before to handle any caching of data and enable bulkification
        handler.bulkBefore();

        // "before" code section omitted

    }
    else
    {
        // Call the bulk after to handle any caching of data and enable bulkification
        handler.bulkAfter();

        // Iterate through the records deleted passing them to the handler.
        if (Trigger.isDelete)
        {
            for (SObject so : Trigger.old)
            {
                handler.afterDelete(so);
            }
        }
        // Iterate through the records inserted passing them to the handler.
        else if (Trigger.isInsert)
        {
            for (SObject so : Trigger.new)
            {
                handler.afterInsert(so);
            }
        }
        // Iterate through the records updated passing them to the handler.
        else if (Trigger.isUpdate)
        {
            for (SObject so : Trigger.old)
            {
                handler.afterUpdate(so, Trigger.newMap.get(so.Id));
            }
        }
    }

    // Perform any post processing
    handler.andFinally();
}
```

What the above means is that when you get to the point of writing code for the actual trigger handler, in an After Trigger, it begins to look something like this:

```
// note: public variables defined earlier
public void afterInsert(SObject so)
{        
    User u = (User)So;
    if(u.ProfileId == ProfileId && u.isActive == true){
        CommUsrId2CtcId3.put(u.Id,u.contactId);

            // can't make a callout here from a list 
            // not certain if I can make a callout here at all on a per record basis
            // appears I need to wait until the finally method to do DML or callouts
            // can't set flag on custom field in user object for tracking
            // can't set a boolean flag to prevent re-entry to this part here since
            // it would be in an iterative loop & repeat up to 200 times
    }        
}

public void afterUpdate(SObject oldSo, SObject newSo)
{

}

public void andFinally()
{
    if(Trigger.IsAfter && Trigger.IsInsert){ 
        ApexSharing_UserHandler(CommUsrId2CtcId3, true);

        // could do DML to custom object which causes @future trigger to fire
        // could do DML on User object to set flag on custom field for tracking
        // could set a boolean flag to prevent re-entry
        // appears I can use a for loop here, but not certain of that

    }    
}
```

I'm trying to refactor code to work with this pattern and am feeling hamstrung by it, but the client insists that it be used. I can respect that, but need to be able to call other handlers to do the work and need to figure out where and how to call them in an efficient manner. Have I drawn the correct conclusions in my commented code about what I can and cannot do using this pattern? Are there other limitations I need to be aware of?

Comment: For what it's worth, that code would throw up all kinds of non-bulkified errors in the code scanner.

Comment: i have much code written over the years in orgs that use this pattern and all my DML or future work is done in `andFinally`.  You collect related -to- the-trigger-set objects in the `bulkBefore` or `bulkAfter` handlers and then in the before/after insert/update handlers, you build up maps of interesting things to do when you hit the `andFinally`.   It is just a different way of thinking

Comment: @sfdcfox Could you elaborate please? Just fixed a couple typos where copy/pasted from wrong sections. As I said, am trying to work with this framework and am not comfortable with it. Your comment isn't very helpful without providing at least one example.

Comment: Thanks @crop1645. That's what I was concluding and trying to convey with my comments, but wanted to obtain some confirmation. Am I on target with respect to calling other classes that they also need to be done from the `andFinally` method?

Comment: before/after insert/update handlers have access to all of the related recs fetched in the bulk before/after handlers. `andFinally` has access to the trigger set, relatedrecs, plus any triggerHandler object maps built by the before/after insert/update handlers. So, if you have classes that work on lists of objects, they would generally get called by the `andFinally`.  Of course, only max of 200 recs per pattern invocation

Comment: So one could pass a list or set from the `andFinally` method to another handler (not looking for a return here) and also use for loops of their own. One could also call external handlers to query related records *before* entering the `Bulk-Before/Bulk-After` code section but not during. That's the essence of what I'm trying to confirm.

Comment: Crmprogdev, simple way of implementing the whole trigger framework is by not have any business logic inside the trigger but have them in apex classes. Then use conditions to determine which class to be called based on the event types. That way you will have more control and easy maintainable scenario.

Comment: @Giene That's very helpful advice! So everything would be called from the `andFinally` method based on the context of the trigger and you'd simply be using it as a "Trigger Dispatcher Main" for each object type using Appleman's terminology?

Comment: Just make the terminology even simpler. Only one trigger per object. Example AccountTrigger. Inside this all the events are handled. Then each event type will have set of flags which you will have to set them to true which in turn uses to call Helper classes based on the flags. But be sure to turn that flag off once the transaction is done. Easy!!!

Comment: @Giene. Ahh, very good! That should work well for my purposes. Would I use a different flag to prevent recursion if I didn't want an afterInsert to cause an afterUpdate execution to fire were I to do an update to same object in the afterInsert handler?

Comment: No. Use the same flag if you do the same operation in both the events. Customize in such a way so that you can use the same functions again and again just like reusable components.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was thinking but wanted to confirm. I appreciate you jumping in to provide your insight. It's been very helpful. I'm equally confident it will be very helpful to others who'll read my question as well. Feel free to post your comments as an answer which I'll be happy to accept.

Comment: @crmprogdev, I am glad it helped. The reason for sharing this information is the pain we have gone through earlier. When SalesForce implementation starts no one realizes this. But down the lane there will be one point of time where there will be a situation of hitting the governor limits somewhere as the applications goes bigger and bigger. Hence, I wanted to share what I have experienced and thank you for asking a Good Question as well.

Comment: I marked up your Question too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Tidy Trigger pattern requires one to think in a particular way

1. Only one triggerhandler per SObject
2. In the bulk before/after methods, collect up all related records that the rest of the trigger handler will need. For example, if the Trigger is on Opportunity, collect into a map all of the Opportunities' Accounts and perhaps a separate map, all of the Opportunities' OLI. I tend to do this in a separate `OpportunityTriggerGateway` class.
3. In the before/after insert/update handlers, you process only a single record at a time but you can refer to the related records' maps in #2. As you process each record, you can save interesting things in collection variables that are part of the triggerhandler object. For example, for those Oppos in the trigger set that are closed won, perhaps you want to note them in a map of `oIdToContractMap` where you build up a Contract record from the Opportunity. You'll use this map in `andFinally`.
4. In the `andFinally` (and typically, the execution of this after the `after` handlers, you will do bulk DML on related objects (in my example, insert Contracts). You can also launch async transactions.  Order-dependent actions are handled here.

As @Giene noted, the handlers for the before/after insert/update/delete events typically invoke another class that does the actual work on an instance of the SObject (with an argument passed to the wherever you collected the related records in #1). These could be service-type classes or simply a wrapper on the SObject with utility methods.

Maintaining via a separate class a static collection of IDs that you don't want to reprocess on any sort of trigger recursion isn't represented in the pattern as documented but easy to add in.

When doing bulk DML in the `andFinally`, if you are supporting partial successes, you'll need to correlate the error on the DML'd record(s) to the triggered item that led to that DML so you can put addError on the sole triggered record and not fail the whole set of up to 200.

Comment: If one needs to query for say a recordTypeId to process records of interest, would that be done in the `andFinally` or could you do it in say the `BulkAfter` or `BulkBefore` section (depending on context) if you wanted to filter records in AfterInsert and/or AfterUpdate methods? Or, does one typically call another class to perform all "setup" queries they might need? As you say, one has to think in a very specific manner when constructing a trigger using this pattern. I'm attempting to learn what that is and how to do it. LOL!

Comment: well, `recordTypeId` by name can be ascertained from Apex Describe so no SOQL is required.  That said, the bulk handlers typically will need to fetch all related records that any of the record-by-record before/after insert/update/delete handlers could need.  Say, you needed to lookup values in the triggered Oppo's Account to decide if an Oppo record requires an `addError`.  Every Oppo's Account has to be prefetched in the bulk handler.  `andFinally` can also do SOQL if the required records aren't needed by the record-by-record before/after insert/update handlers.

Comment: Okay, recordTypeId, was a poor example. LOL. Point was that I might need to query a single value to assign to a public variable for repeated use as a filter. It sounds like the place to query though is in `andFinally`. Was trying to ascertain if one could also do a simple one at the start of either the BulkBefore or After methods since there's no iteration done at that point. From your comments, I'm hearing that using pre-fetch is the practice I should follow if I query anyplace other than in `andFinally`. Very helpful.

Comment: Correct -- although there is always the static variable approach where you query for it when you first need it and retain for all subsequent record-by-record handlers. I tend to do this if I need to check something on some system setup object (User, DatedConversionRate, ...) where I want all triggers to not have to re-fetch this data that can be considered 'constant' for the life of the transaction. That is, I don't use the bulk before/after handlers to query setup objects. As an aside, the next "fresh" org I get to do I'll be looking at the Fawcett pattern

Comment: I work in many different orgs, so am frequently constrained by what's already there. Was told to code new functionality using this pattern and was having trouble figuring out these nuances. You and @Giene have been very helpful. When you use a static boolean to prevent recursion, do you prefer calling it from the trigger handler itself or from a util class? I'm thinking the latter might be preferable.

Comment: separate class; be sure not to use a simple boolean but rather an array of Ids so the triggers will work properly when used by explicit DML (including execute anonymous) where more than 200 sobjects are touched in a single DML statement

Comment: You're talking about creating a collection of Ids for comparison as opposed to a simple on-off switch that prevents re-entry into the start of the trigger? Interesting!

Comment: yes - read this: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000091mJIAQ

Answer (score 1):

Simple way of implementing the whole trigger framework is by not have any business logic inside the trigger but have them in apex classes. Then use conditions to determine which class to be called based on the event types. That way you will have more control and easy maintainable scenario.