# Can't Code Recursive-ish Single-Object Business Requirement -- is it me or the requirement?

Tags: trigger, recursion, executioncontext

Given this background:

- Firstly, a workflow or something on Contact is already in place that updates `Contact.High_School_Lookup__c` when a user saves a change to the value of `Contact.High_School_Numeric_Code__c`
- Secondly, there's a super-complex formula field `Contact.Suggested_OwnerId__c` that involves, among many other things, references to `Contact.High_School_Lookup__r.WhatNot__c`.

What people want me to code trigger functionality for is:

- Detecting changes to `Contact.Suggested_OwnerId__c` -- even when they arise "downstream" from something like a change to `Contact.High_School_Numeric_Code__c` -- and, whenever they happen, updating `Contact.OwnerId` to have the value of `Contact.Suggested_OwnerId__c`

I can't get this thing working.

- BeforeUpdate on Contact doesn't work when someone modifies `Contact.High_School_Numeric_Code__c` because `Contact.Suggested_OwnerId__c` isn't based on `Contact.High_School_Numeric_Code__c`; it's based on `Contact.High_School_Lookup__c`, and that value hasn't yet been set, so `Contact.Suggested_OwnerId__c` is old/blank.
- AfterUpdate on Contact doesn't work because I can't figure out a way to push an UPDATE to `Contact.OwnerId` without getting `SELF_REFERENCE_FROM_TRIGGER` exceptions.  *(Note:  I'm tired, and it's possible I have my recursion-prevention in the wrong place, but I think I have it right...)*

Do I need to tell my end-users that their wish-list inherently involves too many hops of "post-processing a user-update with code-driven updates" to satisfy Salesforce and can't be done, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's me.

Seems I didn't memorize my own lesson from when I commented ["don't make your toInsert/toUpdate collection variables Static in the TidyTrigger pattern"](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192262/#comment290528_192265).

Yay for long walks.

It works fine now as an "After" trigger.